# Rewrite rule on nginx server not applied

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url, url-rewriting

I'm setting up an nginx server this time and wanted to implement my .htaccess from my old apache server.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^proc/?$    process.php    [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Which describes the following behaviour:

If I browse to `http://server.io/proc/`, then it should execute **process.php** , and */proc/* is not a folder!

### Nice to have

Also it would be nice, if a direct execution of **process.php** is disabled - so only via /proc/ allowed.

### What did I try already?

I've tried to input in my *http.conf* and *default.conf* inside the *server{...}*:

```
rewrite ^proc/?$ process.php last;
```

However thank you guys in advance.
Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

finally after searching the web - I found a simple solution for my first problem.

### Solution:

In my **http.conf** create this inside *server{ ... }*:

```
location /proc/ {
   rewrite ^/proc/$ /process.php;
}
```

So, now when I call http://server.io/proc/ *process.php* will be executed.